# View not found after building extbase application with the extension_builder

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I scaffolded an extbase extension for Typo3 4.7 with the [extension_builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) extension (v2.4.0). Everything was included to register a backend module. However, after installing the extension when opening the backend module the following error message is shown:

```
Sorry, the requested view was not found.
The technical reason is: No template was found. View could not
be resolved for action "list".
```

After googling for quite a lot of time I found a [workaround](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-project-extbase-kickstarter/2012-June/000396.html) on the extension_builder mailing list. This requires the user to manually include the folder `extension/Configuration/TypoScript` into the current template's used TypoScript. Inside the files in this folder, there's the needed configuration to make extbase find the right template path.

While this works, it doesn't sound like the right way to do it and it is definitely not desirable to have someone who wants to install the extension make some changes to his template to get a backend module running.

How can I omit this step and still get it working? I looked at other modules where it seems to work without a problem, but I wasn't able to figure out how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure it I understood your problem.

In TYPO3 6.0 and 6.1, the handling of TypoScript settings has been improved for backend modules. You can now put your mappings into `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` which gets included automatically without the need of a root template.

For more details, have a look at the related [bug report](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46511) and the [commit message](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/repository/revisions/0f4e25b8258d5107c36f964f7bd86b7a999c1823).

To resume my answer, a solution would be to upgrade to TYPO3 >=6.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this! I think you understood it completely the right way. While your answer definitely solves the problem, for the project I am working on it is not possible to upgrade to Typo3 6.x because it is relying on other (third-party) extensions that aren't stable in 6.x already. I'm already upvoting but still waiting for some other solution (though I doubt it exists, after reading the bug reports) before I check it as correct answer.

Comment: The meantioned solution in 6.x heavily depends on a refactored bootstrap which was introduced in 6.0. I doubt that backporting this patch for 4.x is possible.

Comment: Ok, so then you're probably right and I will have to upgrade or keep what I have now.